# Can a view limiting device be used in an aircraft requiring two pilots?

Tags: faa-regulations, ifr-navigation, currency

Can a pilot use a VLD for IFR currency if the aircraft requires two pilots? Can it be used while carrying passengers? If so, is this ever done?

I'm thinking of part 121 airline pilots under FAA.

Comment: I don't see why not, I think the only difference is that the other seat has to be occupied by a pilot rated to be PIC, which is usually done with a training captain. Most commercial passenger flights are flown on IFR flight plans anyway,  even without a VLD. I don't think IFR currency is much of a problem for airline pilots.

Comment: @RonBeyer Actually, depending on the types of routes they fly, airline pilots can definitely have problems with currency. Long haul, multi-crew pilots can get very few takeoffs and landings. And, although the flights are all IFR, to count for currency, as I understand it, the approach has to be in actual or simulated IMC

Comment: Good point,  I was thinking more of the regional pilots. I don't think using a VLD is a problem though as long as 91.109 is followed, I haven't seen anything in the FARs that seems to say you can't conduct training on revenue flights.

Comment: Possibly answered by [FAR Appendix F to part 121](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=9627b93d29278bf5a8f43219ad551aeb&mc=true&node=pt14.3.121&rgn=div5#ap14.3.121_11500.f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no regulation against doing so provided that the third person in the cockpit is type rated for PIC privileges on the aircraft and has a waiver from the FAA to operate the aircraft as a single pilot (they are available with some additional training.)  In practice, this would almost never occur both for safety reasons and cost.  In addition full motion simulators are available for most aircraft type rated for a two person flight crew, so it would just be more feasible to carry out the training in one of these using simulated IMC, which is arguably more realistic and accurate than flying the real thing under the hood.